# How to hide TreeListView error message about a row with missing column details?

Tags: c#, .net, listview, objectlistview, treelistview

I have an TreeListView component with 2 columns: "a" and "b".

In my list I sometimes have both "a" and "b", but sometimes only "a".

How I can rid of the following message in column "b" (in rows that doesn't contains "b")?

**"'b' is not a parameter-less method, property or field of type..."**

Comment: Show your current code to receive feedback/help, please.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are talking about a `TreeListView` in the `ObjectListView` project.

If so, you will have to install an `AspectGetter` on your 'b' column. Have that aspect getter return null when there isn't a 'b' property.

```
this.olvColumnB.AspectGetter = delegate(object x) {
    ModelWithPropertyB model = x as ModelWithPropertyB;
    return model == null ? null : model.B;
}
```

Comment: If the return value of B in the example above is not nullable then you can cast to an object to avoid the compiler complaint about not being able to find a conversion. return model == null ? null : (object)model.B;

Answer (score 2):

The solution with the current version of TreeListView (2.8.1, not sure when this was added) is to set:

```
BrightIdeasSoftware.TreeListView.IgnoreMissingAspects = true;
```